# pl/sql stored procedure writes to a different table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Good day Everyone,

I am fairly new to pl/sql stored procedure. I have a script that calls a stored procedure that will execute many stored procedures sequentially. Now my problem is one of my stored procedures writes to a different table instead to the table that it should write to. But when i run the stored procedure on its own it write to the correct table. Any ideas on why is this happening?

Comment: Can you share the stored procedures? Otherwise we are all going to be playing guessing games...

Comment: can you give your code so that we can explain based upon ur requirement.

Comment: If you don't want to share, you can do some creative rearranging. Move the SP you are having problems with to be executed earlier / later, and see if it still writes to the wrong table. And then figure out what the logic is behind the anomalies. That should get you close to a solution...

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies. I cannot really share it because of the confidentiality. @PeterAbolins i would try your suggestion

Comment: make some test case to get it.. if possible here!!!

Comment: Is ist maybe, that you have different schemas containing tables with the same name? Which would mean, that it depends on the user executing the procedure which table is written to.

Comment: Confidentiality is fine. The idea is to narrow down the problem space. Not sure how many SP's you are calling, but if only one is having issues then the problem has to be with either: The main script / SP (the one calling all the others); or, the SP running just before the problem one; or... the SP that has a problem. Given that the problem SP runs fine on its own, my guess would be that the SP running just before has a problem which is propagating forward...

Comment: @PeterAbolins i am currently reading the SPs before and after the SP that has having a problem,

Comment: @SabarishMahalingam i would share it to you later if i narrow it down

Comment: @sers i have re-read the SP and the possibility of having schemas containing tables with the same name are 0

Comment: Are you creating the procedure using an [Invoker Rights clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm#i2065815) and is the stored procedure referring to the correct table owner?

Comment: what kind of script is it, a shell script or any other programming language..?